# Sign and send transaction (call contract function)

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I am using ethereumjs-accounts providerfor transaction signer in HookedWeb3Provider. And I am trying to call contract function which send tokens. 
It's my params for sign transaction.

```
let tx_params = {
        nonce: '00',
        gasPrice: '100',
        gasLimit: '100',
        from: account,
        to: contractParams.address,
        value: '00',
        data: '' //what should I place here to call contract function with arguments?
    };
```

then I am calling sign method:

```
signTransaction(tx_params, (err, hash)=>{})
```

and receiving hash

```
0xf86280820100832fefd894efcc9f9a5cb3d6062c18eeffdf90a29bb771fccc80801ba07c0226eb53fc4c8031a5346389fb17125b37ca96bec2ce5dd651808c8356ea9aa0aef5cb9e2a0426a6af2193a0fd9d3ec09f334614594faa54be17d9ddd64b72b1
```

A didn't understand how to send transaction with web3js and put there a signed transaction (or hash?)

```
this.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction();
```

Comment: See this : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsign  &  https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction

Comment: Using https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract and contract methods will be simpler and you won't have to manually create the `data`.  Otherwise for the `data` value you have to use the [ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI), compute the Method ID and encode the arguments.

Comment: Thank you.
In this case I don't understand how to get sign Object. Agter signTransaction method call I am receiving hash string, but not object..

Comment: @eth For function with address, address, value and description -  getting code should be like this?:

`contractInstance.sendFunds.getData('0x7a16108bc3c2751a5a54ca077d4d01aa43ee5c34', '0xdd7b798cbfe06af77fdc4b64e48f71672595adcf', 1, 'hello');`

Comment: @eth and one more stupid question. How to  get a proof that transaction have been signed? And then how to pass this result do `web3.eth.sendRawTransaction`?

Comment: Method `signTransaction` returns you not a hash but rather signed transactions.  Signed transaction is a sequence of bytes, not javascript object, and you got this sequences of bytes in hexadecimal format.  Hashes are byte sequences too, and in Ethereum world hashes are usually represented in hexadecimal format, that's why signed transaction looks like a hash for you.  Though hashes in Ethereum are usually 256-bit long, i.e. usually contain 64 hexadecimal characters, but your signed transaction is definitely longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In web3js Version 1.0.0**

The data here should be the encoded ABI of the contract method you are trying to execute. See how to encode ABI definition of your contract method [here.](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi)

For example: If your method call is `buyItem('Pasta')`

Then you would do something like this

```
var encodedABI = contractInstance.methods.buyItem(web3.utils.asciiToHex('Pasta')).encodeABI();
  var tx = {
    from: defaultAddress,
    to: contractInstance.options.address,
    gas: 2000000,
    data: encodedABI,
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

With ethers.js v5:

1. create your smart contract instance

   `const instance = new Contract(address, abi, signerOrProvider)`

or just the interface

`const interface = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi)`

2. encode data

   `const data = instance.interface.encodeFunctionData('yourFuncName', [inputParams])`